# Method cannot be called on Option due to unsatisfied trait bounds, needs to be iterator

Tags: rust, traits

I know that the `cloned()` here is unnecessary but I want to know why it requires that `Values` implement the `Iterator` trait.

***Minimal reproducible example***

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum Values {
    Foo,
    Bar
}

fn f(mut values: impl Iterator<Item=Values>) {
    // (HERE) Why to clone Option<Values> should implement Iterator???
    if let Some(v1) = values.next().cloned() {
        if let Some(v2) = values.next() {
            println!("Foo");
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut values = vec![
        Values::Foo,
        Values::Bar
    ];
    
    f(values.into_iter());
}
```

***Error***

```
error[E0599]: the method `cloned` exists for enum `Option<Values>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:8:37
    |
8   |       if let Some(v1) = values.next().cloned() {
    |                                       ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Option<Values>` due to 
unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Option<Values>: Iterator`
            which is required by `&mut Option<Values>: Iterator`
```

***Playground***
[link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e3b244e54a2d02d240709c635dfeae31)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two applicable `cloned` functions, `Iterator::cloned` and `Option::cloned`.
The `Option::cloned` does not apply in this case, since it is only available for types like `Option<&T>`. In the example it is a `Option<Value>` which is not a reference.
`Iterator::cloned` could apply, if the trait bound `Option<Values>: Iterator`
is satisfied, which is why this is part of the suggestion.
Both functions would be wrong in this context to use.

Maybe you meant to use the `clone` function which would indeed be unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

`Option::cloned()` is only defined if the value inside is a reference. For example, you could call it if the paramters was `values: impl Iterator<Item = &Values>`, which would make the result of `next()` an `Option<&Values>`.

You parameter `values: impl Iterator<Item = Values>` means that the iterator owns the values. The values are moved out of the iterator as you iterate through it so the clone would be unnecessary. I assume that this is just an artifact of it being a minimum reproducible example.

---

The error is confusing because the compiler is trying to help you by suggesting traits you could implement that do have a `cloned()` method, and the choices are:

- `Option<&T>`
- `I` where `I: Iterator<Item = &T>`

It unfortunately has chosen the one that doesn't apply in your situation.